# DRY T-SQL case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a DRYer way to write this case statement?

```
case 
  when try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) >= 0 and try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) <= 5 then 1
  ...
  when try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) > 20 then 2
  else -9
end
```

This syntax doesn't work:

```
case try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD])
  when between 0 and 5 then 1
  when between 6 and 10 then 2
  when between 11 and 20 then 3
  when > 20 then 4
  else -9
end
```

** edit **

Sample data:

```
0 to 2
> 10
6
```

As `TRY_CONVERT` would only work on discrete values, I'm not certain that a sub-query would be useful.  Currently, I'm handling range values in a different code sub-branch.

Comment: You could use a CTE or derived table to avoid repetition of the try_convert, but that's about all I can think of that you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a subquery that gets the try_convert result, then the outer query runs the case statement. Something like this:

```
-- use equivalence
SELECT  CASE 
        WHEN s.converted >= 0 AND s.converted < 6 THEN 1
        WHEN s.converted >= 6 AND s.converted < 11 THEN 2
        WHEN s.converted >= 11 AND s.converted < THEN 3
        WHEN s.converted > 20 THEN 4
        END calc
FROM    (
            SELECT converted = try_convert([MIXED_USE_FIELD])
            FROM TABLE
        ) s
```

---

```
-- use BETWEEN
SELECT  CASE 
        WHEN s.converted BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN 1
        WHEN s.converted BETWEEN 6 AND 9 THEN 2
        WHEN s.converted BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 3
        WHEN s.converted > 20 THEN 0 
        END calc
FROM    (
            SELECT converted = try_convert([MIXED_USE_FIELD])
            FROM TABLE
        ) s
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this:

```
...
    case
        when tc.c between 0 and 5 then 1
        when tc.c between 6 and 10 then 2
        when tc.c between 11 and 20 then 3
        when tc.c > 20 then 4
        else -9
    end
from ... as a
    outer apply (select ry_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) as tc) as c
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not attempt to refactor in this case.  If your goal is readable, maintainable code, then a sufficiently descriptive name in lieu of `try_convert()` will be just as wordy as the function itself.  There's not enough additional clarity to justify the additional indirection.

SQL isn't a pretty language. Don't try to put lipstick on a pig.

```
select
  case 
    when try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) between  0 and  5 then 1
    when try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) between  6 and 10 then 2
    when try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) between 11 and 20 then 3
    when try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) > 20              then 4
    else -9
  end
from MyTable t1
```

versus:

```
select
  case 
    when [MIXED USE FIELD as int] between  0 and  5 then 1
    when [MIXED USE FIELD as int] between  6 and 10 then 2
    when [MIXED USE FIELD as int] between 11 and 20 then 3
    when [MIXED USE FIELD as int] > 20              then 4
    else -9
  end
from MyTable t1
cross apply (
  select try_convert(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) as [MIXED USE FIELD as int]
) t2
```

---

Another approach is to rewrite this the SQL way: encapsulate your business rules in your data, not in your code.  Move those ranges to a table.

```
CREATE TABLE MyRangeFilterTable (
  [RangeFrom] int DEFAULT -2147483648
 ,[RangeTo]   int DEFAULT  2147483647
 ,[Value]     int
)

INSERT MyRangeFilterTable VALUES
  ( 0,   5, 1)
 ,( 6,  10, 2)
 ,(11,  20, 3)
 ,(20, DEFAULT, 4)
 ,(NULL, NULL, -9)

SELECT
  [Value]
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN MyRangeFilterTable
  ON (TRY_CONVERT(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) BETWEEN [RangeFrom] AND [RangeTo])
  OR (TRY_CONVERT(int, [MIXED USE FIELD]) IS NULL AND [RangeFrom] IS NULL)
```

Now you can alter the rules without changing your code.

Comment: Only problem with yours is that joining on the try_convert could be really slow if there's a lot of records. I like the MyRangeFilterIdea, but might be better to do a subquery (or define a function) rather than a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I use CROSS APPLY for the conversion and some arithmetic for the case statement. Try it out:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ([MIXED USE FIELD] VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES  ('1'),('6'),('15'),('21'),('-1');

SELECT  [MIXED USE FIELD],
        CASE
            WHEN MUF_int BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN CEILING(muf_int/5.0)
            WHEN MUF_int > 20 THEN 4
            ELSE -9
        END case_results
FROM @Table
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT,[MIXED USE FIELD])) AS CA(MUF_int)
```

Results:

```
MIXED USE FIELD case_results
--------------- ---------------------------------------
1               1
6               2
15              3
21              4
-1              -9
```